# Get actual component in HashTree in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

We have a project with the following structure:

```
-TestPlan
 |- ThreadGroup
   |- Test-Group-1 (SimpleController to group our tests)
   | |- test-case-1 (ParamterizedController with all test properties)
   | | |- ${testFolder}::${testCase}::Request (HttpRequest)
   | | |- ${testFolder}::${testCase}::Validation (HttpRequest)
   | |- test-case-2 (ParamterizedController with all test properties)
   | |- test-case-3 (ParamterizedController with all test properties)
   |- Test-Group-2 (SimpleController to group our tests)
   | |- test-case-4 (ParamterizedController with all test properties)
   |- Test-Group-3 (SimpleController to group our tests)
     |- test-case-5 (ParamterizedController with all test properties)
```

Now we want to use the controller names as variables in our tests (for example for the HTTP Request we want `Test-Group-1::test-case-1::Request`).

We already tried a solution with `HashTree` and `SearchByClass` to get the controller, but it returns just all controllers in the tree and we don't know the actual position.

Is their any solution? We do not want to duplicate the test case id in other variables.